# Ка вывести все значения из базы в Ajax?

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Доброго времени друзья помогите пожалуйста.

я запрашиваю все из базы

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM head";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $assocRes = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo json_encode($assocRes);
}
```

И пытаюсь вывести всё яваскриптом в столбик но выводится только первое значение из базы

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://localhost/javascript/forsess.php",
dataType: "json",
success: function(session){
if(session.id==session.id){
$("body").prepend("<div class='forpost'></div>");
$(".forpost").prepend("<div class='post'><p>"+data.text+"</p></div>");
   }   }});
```

как мне вывести все значения разом?

Comment: Порадовала строка:

    if(session.id==session.id) // Могут быть варианты? ))

А вообще, чтоб "вывести все значения разом", надо их или подготовить на сервере (скомпоновать всё в строку) или же, если на клиенте, то перебором массива (вы же именно егои передаете).

Comment: объект дата выше) это аякс в аяксе)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Доброго времени друзья помогите
> пожалуйста.
>
> я запрашиваю все из базы
>
> $query = "SELECT * FROM head"; 
> $result = mysql_query($query); 
> $assocRes =
> mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
>
> echo json_encode($assocRes); }

Запрашивать то запрашиваете... Но выводите только 1ю запись.

```
# get_all.php
$query = "SELECT * FROM head";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Мы скомпоновали массив всех данных. В итоге у нас получился массив массивов данных :), а не один массив данных.

Запрашиваем эти данные из javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/javascript/get_all.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var row = data[i];
            $("body").prepend("<div class='forpost'></div>");
            $(".forpost").prepend("<div class='post'><p>"+row.text+"</p></div>");
        }
    }
});
```

думаю как то так должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё работает!

Answer (score 0):

Может быть `$assocRes = mysql_fetchrow($result);` ?

p.s. переходите на mysqli.